# Javascript alternative for requestSubmit(). Since safari does not support it

Tags: javascript, html, forms, onclick, form-submit

Im trying to submit my form with Javascript. By clicking a button, or pressing enter. `type="submit"` would generally do all of this. The issue is that I have a "next" button that should activate a function that shows the next part of my form. So I used the following code to submit my form:

```html
// Form:
<form name="hours" method="post" id="HoursForm" class="form">

// nextForm() goes to next part in form.
<button id="NextButton" type="button" class="..." onclick="nextForm()">Next</button>
<button id="SaveButton" type="button" class="..." onclick="document.hours.requestSubmit();">Save</button>
```

The save button will trigger my event listener that does the following:

```js
hoursForm.addEventListener("submit", function() {

    // If form is submitted and valid, remove the ability to submit again.
    window.removeEventListener('keyup', submitFormWithEnter, false);
    saveButton.disabled = true;
});
```

When the user presses the "enter" button either the "next" or "save" functionality will be triggered.

```js
/**
 * When pressed enter, next part of form should be shown or form should be submitted.
 * 
 * @param {Event} e 
 */
 function submitFormWithEnter(e) {
    if (e.key === 'Enter') {

        // If the next button is visible, trigger the next part. Else if the last part of the form is visible, submit the form.
        if (!nextButton.classList.contains('d-none')) {
            nextForm();
        } else if (!kmPrivateField.classList.contains('d-none')) {

            // Submit form.
            hoursForm.requestSubmit();
        }
    }
}
```

**So this works all fine untill we use safari.** As shown in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/requestSubmit). Is there an alternative for this functionality?

I tried to use `document.getElementById('HoursForm').dispatchEvent(new Event('submit'));` in my `onclick` event (SaveButton). But this only triggers the submit event. And does not submit the form or validate the fields (e.g. `min`, `max` attributes are skipped).

`.submit()` does submit the form, but does not trigger the submit event. Making the user be able to spam the button and submit the form multiple times.

**So, what I need:**

- Submit form by clicking the "save" button, at all times.
- Submit form by using "enter" key, but only when at the end of the form (last page/part).
- Make user be able to only submit the form once. After button is clicked or form is saved with the "enter" button disable the submit functionality.
- Support for basicly all common browsers except IE. E.g. [this is fine](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reportValidity#:%7E:text=cva%2Dreportvalidity%2Ddev-,Browser%20compatibility,-Report%20problems%20with).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okey I already fixed it.

I changed a couple of lines:

```html
// Added dispatch event AND submit(); I previously only used one of them.
<button id="SaveButton" type="button" class="..." onclick="document.getElementById('HoursForm').dispatchEvent(new Event('submit')); document.hours.submit();">Opslaan</button>
```

In Javascript I changed `.requestSubmit()` to `.submit()`. And added dispatch event to trigger the event.

```js
/**
 * When pressed enter, next part of form should be shown or form should be submitted. Also a little `&&` in my if statement to validate the form.
 * 
 * @param {Event} e 
 */
 function submitFormWithEnter(e) {
    if (e.key === 'Enter') {

        // If the next button is visible, trigger the next part. Else if the save button is visible trigger the submitform part. 
        if (!nextButton.classList.contains('d-none')) {
            nextForm();
        } else if (!kmPrivateField.classList.contains('d-none') && hoursForm.reportValidity()) {

            // Submit form.
            hoursForm.dispatchEvent(new Event('submit'));
            hoursForm.submit();
        }
    }
}
```

This fixed it for me.

Comment: Using `form.dispatchEvent(new SubmitEvent('submit'))` alone worked for me, without `form.submit()`.